# Typing text animation can't control width

Tags: jquery, css

So basically I have this typing text animation where the some javascript changes a message every 3 seconds and a css keyframe is used to "retype" the text before the message is changed by my jquery code.  Currently it works fine however the width is static, so for the smaller worlds the width is still set to 7ch and it ends up looking silly.  I tried a few different work arounds such as setting the width to auto, setting the div with then setting the width to inherit however all ideas failed.

```css
@keyframes terminal {
  0% {width:0}
  20% {width:0}
  50% {width:7ch}
  70% {width:7ch}
  100% {width:0}
}
#terminal-text {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 1em 0 .5em 0;
  padding: 0;
  animation: terminal 3s infinite;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-right: 4px solid black;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<center style="display: flex;">
    <h1 style="padding-right:20px;">We</h1>
    <h1 id="terminal-text">innovate.</h1>
</center>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var i = 0;
    words = ['architect.','build.','design.','code.','develop.','innovate.'];
    setInterval(function() {
      $("#terminal-text").text(words[i]);
      i++;
      if (i > words.length) {
        i=0;
      }
    },3000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than animating `width`, animate `max-width`:

```js
var i = 0;
words = ['architect.','build.','design.','code.','develop.','innovate.'];
setInterval(function() {
  $("#terminal-text").text(words[i]);
  i++;
  if (i > words.length) {
    i=0;
  }
},3000);
```

```css
@keyframes terminal {
  0% {max-width:0}
  20% {max-width:0}
  50% {max-width:100%}
  70% {max-width:100%}
  100% {max-width:0}
}
#terminal-text {
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 1em 0 .5em 0;
  padding: 0;
  animation: terminal 3s infinite;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-right: 4px solid black;
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<center style="display: flex;">
    <h1 style="padding-right:20px;">We</h1>
    <h1 id="terminal-text">innovate.</h1>
</center>
```

Comment: Omg thank you it works, all though if you wouldn't mind can you explain to me why max-width is working but width is not?

Comment: Essentially you can't animate from `0` to `auto`, but you can animate from `0` to `100%`. You wouldn't want to animate to 100% `width`, because the width would always be 100% of the width of the containing element, but if you animate `max-width` instead, then it will only increase the width as much as is needed to display the contents of the element.

Comment: Makes sense ty.

Comment: Could simplify a bit by starting `i` at -1 and then changing to `$("#terminal-text").text(words[++i % words.length]);`